# Assembly code x86

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, intel, compiler-optimization

so im a total noob at assembly code and reading them as well

so i have a simple c code

```
void saxpy()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
  float product = a*x[i];
  z[i] = product + y[i];
}
}
```

and the equivalent assembly code when compiled with

```
gcc -std=c99 -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize -S code.c -o code-O3.s
```

gives me the follows asssembly code

```
saxpy:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
movss   a(%rip), %xmm1
xorl    %eax, %eax
.p2align 4,,10
.p2align 3
.L3:
movss   x(%rax), %xmm0
addq    $4, %rax
mulss   %xmm1, %xmm0
addss   y-4(%rax), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, z-4(%rax)
cmpq    $262144, %rax
jne .L3
rep ret
.cfi_endproc
```

i do understand that loop unrolling has taken place 
but im not able to understand the intention and idea behind

```
addq    $4, %rax
mulss   %xmm1, %xmm0
addss   y-4(%rax), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, z-4(%rax)
```

Can someone explain, the usage of 4, and 
what does the statements mean
    y-4(%rax)

Comment: 4 is the size of a float

Comment: can u tell me  what does  y-4(%rax) does,

assume, that i have the loop to run 20 times. 
after optimization what would be my static and dynamic insns count  ?

Comment: Also, what is the need to add an immediate value 4 to rax register. which is done as per the statement
   

 "addq    $4, %rax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x`, `y`, and `z` are global arrays.  You left out the end of the listing where the symbols are declared.

I [put your code on godbolt for you](https://goo.gl/MSLMBm), with the necessary globals defined (and fixed the indenting).  Look at the bottom.

BTW, there's no unrolling going on here.  There's one each scalar single-precision mul and add in the loop.  Try with `-funroll-loops` to see it unroll.

[With `-march=haswell`, gcc will use an FMA instruction](https://goo.gl/OHYomB).  If you un-cripple the compiler by leaving out `-fno-tree-vectorize`, and `#define ARRAY_SIZE` is small, like 100, it fully unrolls the loop with mostly 32byte FMA ymm instructions, ending with some 16byte FMA xmm.

> Also, what is the need to add an immediate value 4 to rax register.
>   which is done as per the statement "addq $4, %rax"

The loop increments a pointer by 4 bytes, instead of using a scaled-index addressing mode.

---

Look at the links on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86.  Also, single-stepping through code with a debugger is often a good way to make sure you understand what it's doing.

Comment: Hey Peter, right i realised no unrolling here, much later than i posted this. Thanks for clarification on the 4 bytes thing. 

i gotta read up on lot of this stuff.
in the mean time, could you tell me the best way to debug assembly code step by step other than gdb.

any other compiler or method or tools i can use ?

Comment: @sarath: Any debugger should be able to single-step. It's nice when register that were changed by the previous instruction are highlighted.  For performance-tuning, performance counters (Linux `perf`) are nice for seeing whether your code is bottlenecked by something you didn't expect.  It depends what you're trying to do, but looking at asm output from optimizing compilers, and figuring out why they did what they did, is often useful.  Esp. when you come across cases where they *can't* optimize, you'll maybe realize you need to give the compiler more info (`__restrict__`, alignment, unsigned)